# Selecting particular option from a combo box should make textbox field mandatory to enter text

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a combo box in a form which has two options : correct and incorrect. There is another textbox field which is set not required in Required field property of the table but when combo box selection makes "incorrect", it should automatically force user to fill in textbox i.e. mandatory to fill in textbox
Could anyone please help me out how to fix this.

Thanks!

Comment: My code : Private Sub Combo63_AfterUpdate()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `After Update` event of the combo box check the selected value. If it is "incorrect" set the focus to the textbox and then use the `After Update` event of the text box to verify the conditions for filling the text box are satisfied otherwise reset the focus back to the text box (and possibly put on a message box to explain why).

Comment: Finally it worked, I used onchange event and set focus to textbox then used lost focus event and checked condition for emty textbox...